# Access GKE pods with Cloud functions using Google Serverless VPC

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-kubernetes-engine

I have created a GKE private cluster, with some pods live in it. Now I want to integrate my pods with cloud function provided by GCP. To achieve this, I use Serverless VPC access, because my GKE cluster lived on a custom network on another region and use Internal Load Balancer for my pods.

It seems successful, because I have tested to access my pods internal IP from GCE lived in the same network and tested to access my GCE VM from Cloud Function, but when I try to access my pod internal IP from the Cloud Function, it always returns timeout.

```
The HTTP request failed with error %s
Get http://172.16.0.42: dial tcp 172.16.0.42:80: i/o timeout
```

I expect the Serverless VPC access will connect my cloud function to my pod Internal IP, like it connects my cloud function to GCP VM with same network with my pod.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question was asked almost 3 years ago. May answer will be useful for somebody.

We can make internal load balancer using `LoadBalancer` type and annotation `cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"`

Should be smth like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service_name
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
  labels:
...
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
...
  ports:
...
```